# How do I get actual name of checkbox instead of datarowview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

How do I loop through all checkboxes loaded by

```
public void loadTags()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlCommand selectTags = new SqlCommand("select tag from Categories", cs))
    {
        cs.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAd = new SqlDataAdapter(selectTags))
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dataAd.Fill(dt);
        }
        cs.Close();
    }
    list1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

xaml:

```
<ListView Name="list1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="307,52,0,0" Height="132" Width="293">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding tag}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

do you have any idea how do I get now all tag names (checkboxes) using loop?

If I hardcode these checkboxes straight into grid this loop is working. But if I get them straight from the database i only get *System.Data.DataRowView* instead of *spo, inf, war etc* if these checkboxes are checked.

```
foreach (var items in list1.Items)
{
    if (items.IsChecked == true)
    {
        list.Add("CategoryMulti like '%" + item.Content.ToString() + "%'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either store the reference to `dt.DefaultView` in a `DataView` field, or cast the items:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in list1.Items.OfType<DataRowView>())
{
    //...
}
```

You still need to store the value of the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` in a column of your `DataTable`. If there is no such column, you should add it to the `DataTable` before you bind to it in the view:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Checked", typeof(bool)) { DefaultValue = false });
...
```

---

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding tag}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked} "/>
```

You could then get the value of the column in your loop like this:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in list1.Items.OfType<DataRowView>())
{
    bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(item["Checked"]);
    //...
}
```

Comment: getting error of _System.ArgumentException: 'Checked is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table .'_

Comment: ...which means that there is no such column in your `DataTable` as I wrote.

Comment: I am sorry man. I know that you are trying to explain it to me as stupid as you can. But I just don't understand that.. still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you add the column to your `DataTable` in the `loadTags()` method?

Comment: I am sorry for being stupid. I am looking to that several hours now and I cant use my brain anymore i guess... Last question would be how do I get the name of checkbox now instead of true/false?

Comment: `item["tag"].ToString();`

Comment: Man, thank you so much. You have no idea how you made my day easier. Thank you so much. And really sorry for being stupid. I am still trying and learning. @mm8

Comment: @Cabry: No worries, you are welcome! I am glad to help.